# How to include user's promos in ride estimates for Uber

Tags: uber-api

I want to show a user ride estimates that include any promos or credits that they have on their account already. Is there a way to do this?

I'm assuming that the estimate received from GET /estimates/price do not include the promos, but i see that POST /requests/estimate may have a fare breakdown which specifies the portion of the estimate that is the promotion. So would that include the promos which are already on the user's account?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, POST /requests/estimate v1.2 includes promotions on an account, since you are using that specific bearer token for the estimate. Keep in mind this bearer token must be authorized with the 'request' scope.

This is reflected in the documentation here: https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/requests-estimate-post

"type": "promotion",
       "value": -2.00,
       "name": "Promotion"

Apparently there is an issue when it is a non-upfront fare, however. When it is a non-upfront fare promotions are not taken into account on the estimate (although would still apply for the ride). Promotions not reflecting on the estimate on non-upfront fares is considered a bug and being worked on to be resolved, but I do not have an ETA for that resolution.